# Sorting tree format file

Tags: java, sorting

I have to sort my text file in specific format.
My file:

```
AAAA
    BBBB
        CCCC
        CCCC
        CCCC
AAAA
    BBBB
        CCCC
    BBBB
        CCCC
```

And I have to sort separately `AAAA (first)`, `BBBB (second)` in `AAAA` and `CCCC (third)` in `BBBB` but I don't know how to make it. I know that between `AAAA`, `BBBB`, `CCCC` are 4 spaces.

I can parse it to JSON and I think that would be working but there is maybe some simple way to sort that file. Can you give me some ideas?

I read about getting whole `AAAA` paragraph but what inside?

Result doesn't have to be with spaces (like example) but it's visually better.

Please give me your opinion about that.

Example:

```
Def
    Abc
        Xyz
        Ghi
        Def
Abc
    Def
        Xyz
    Abc
        Abc
```

Output of my program:

```
Abc
    Abc
        Abc
    Def
        Xyz
Def
    Abc
        Def
        Ghi
        Xyz
```

Edit: Name AAAA, BBBB, CCCC will never be the same.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  What output are you expecting?  And why are you thinking about JSON when there's nothing in your input file that looks like JSON?

Comment: Your question is too broad for StackOverflow, please visit the [help] and read [ask] before posting.

Comment: You should at least show the output/result you want here.

Comment: I understand exactly what the OP wants to do, but explaining all the necessary data structure fundamentals required to understand a solution would be much longer than SO has room for.

Comment: You create an object `Node` with two fields `String name` and `List<Node> children`, and make it implement `Comparable<Node>` to order by `name`. You then load the data in, sort the root list and every `children` list, and print the result back out.

Comment: Okay, sorry, my english is so bad and I cant give you best feedback but look at examples, maybe that now will be better.

Comment: @FFFs Here's a hint: You have a nested data structure, and to do the sort you want you must duplicate all the higher-level keys in each record, sort the records, then remove the duplicated keys.  Your question is actually interesting, but you have not followed the requirements for posting on this site.

Comment: @JimGarrison If you just make them lists of `Comparable` objects, then duplicates can be handled too. See [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189689/sorting-tree-format-file#comment79341686_46189689). Duplicates will retain original order, as guaranteed by `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: @Andreas I think you have misunderstood the nested structure of the problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison Not at all. If file has a `Foo` node with nested `Y` and `X`, and another root `Foo` node with nested `B` and `A`, then result will be `Foo` with `X` and `Y`, and `Foo` with `A` and `B`. The children of each root node are independently sorted, and root nodes are sorted, but nodes of same name retain their original relative order. There is nothing in the question that limits nodes to be uniquely named within their parent, and nothing that states they should be merged if they have same name.

Comment: Name AAAA, BBBB, CCCC will never be the same.

Comment: @FFFs The logic [I described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189689/sorting-tree-format-file#comment79341686_46189689) won't care if they are. It can handle it, but will work great if nodes with same parent are all uniquely named. However, if duplicates won't exist, you can eliminate the sorting step by changing the `children` list to be a `TreeSet<Node>` instead. Same for the list of root nodes.

Comment: Ok, I will check it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you can use this program to solve your problem, I have used here the Directory datastructure::

```
class Directory {
    public String name;
    public List<Directory > children;
}
```

So, with the help of this program you will get a list of Directory in the required sorted format. This is the output when I will print the list, which is in teh sorted format.

[Directory [name=Abc, children=[Directory [name=Abc, children=[Directory [name=Abc, children=null]]], Directory [name=Def, children=[Directory [name=Xyz, children=null]]]]], Directory [name=Def, children=[Directory [name=Abc, children=[Directory [name=Def, children=null], Directory [name=Ghi, children=null], Directory [name=Xyz, children=null]]]]]]

See the program it is self explanatory and if you have any doubt you can comment.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Input.txt"));
        List<Directory> dirList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                int spaces = line.length() - line.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
                while (spaces == 0) {
                    Directory directory = new Directory();
                    directory.name = line.replaceAll(" ", "");
                    directory.children = new ArrayList<>();
                    line = br.readLine();
                    spaces = line.length() - line.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
                    while (spaces == 4) {
                        Directory directory2 = new Directory();
                        directory2.name = line.replaceAll(" ", "");
                        directory2.children = new ArrayList<>();
                        line = br.readLine();
                        if (line == null)
                            break;
                        spaces = line.length() - line.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
                        while (spaces == 8) {
                            Directory directory3 = new Directory();
                            directory3.name = line.replaceAll(" ", "");
                            directory2.children.add(directory3);
                            line = br.readLine();
                            if (line == null)
                                break;
                            spaces = line.length() - line.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
                        }
                        Collections.sort(directory2.children);
                        directory.children.add(directory2);
                    }
                    Collections.sort(directory.children);
                    System.out.println(directory);
                    dirList.add(directory);
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            Collections.sort(dirList);
            System.out.println(dirList);
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}

class Directory implements Comparable<Directory> {
    public String name;
    public List<Directory> children;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Directory [name=" + name + ", children=" + children + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Directory other = (Directory) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(children);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Directory o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also use a simple map and store the index in the format of 0.0.0, 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2 and then you can sort it, it would be easier to do like that.